# K-map & Boolean Expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

After obtaining the result from Karnaugh map: $$F = ad+a'b'c'+a'b'c$$

Can I still further simplify the expression to:

```
F = ad+a'b'c'+a'b'c
  = ad+a'b'(c'+c)
  = ad+a'b'
```

or should I just leave it as how it should be?

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of a K-map is to group as many terms together, so yes, you should simplify.

In fact, you should have obtained the simpler expression from the K-map in the first place, so take another look at the K-map you have and note how indeed you could have created a larger grouping.